# How to run torch.distributed.run such that one can run two instances of the script without errors or deadlocks?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, distributed-computing

when I run

```
python -m torch.distributed.run --nproc_per_node=8 --master_addr="127.0.0.1" --master_port=$RANDOM ~/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_dist_maml_l2l.py --manual_loads_name l2l_resnet12rfs_cifarfs_adam_cl_80k
```

I get the error:

```
====> about to start train loop
Starting training!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/site-packages/learn2learn/algorithms/maml.py", line 159, in adapt
    gradients = grad(loss,
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 226, in grad
    return Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 16.00 MiB (GPU 6; 39.59 GiB total capacity; 265.23 MiB already allocated; 10.19 MiB free; 282.00 MiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
learn2learn: Maybe try with allow_nograd=True and/or allow_unused=True ?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miranda9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_dist_maml_l2l.py", line 216, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/miranda9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_dist_maml_l2l.py", line 161, in main
    train(args=args)
  File "/home/miranda9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_dist_maml_l2l.py", line 196, in train
    meta_train_iterations_ala_l2l(args, args.agent, args.opt, args.scheduler)
  File "/home/miranda9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/training/meta_training.py", line 149, in meta_train_iterations_ala_l2l
    train_loss, train_loss_std, train_acc, train_acc_std = meta_learner(task_dataset, call_backward=True)
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/miranda9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/meta_learners/maml_meta_learner.py", line 371, in forward
    meta_loss, meta_loss_std, meta_acc, meta_acc_std = forward(meta_learner=self,
  File "/home/miranda9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/meta_learners/maml_meta_learner.py", line 312, in forward
    loss, acc = fast_adapt(
  File "/home/miranda9/ultimate-utils/ultimate-utils-proj-src/uutils/torch_uu/meta_learners/maml_meta_learner.py", line 266, in fast_adapt
    learner.adapt(adaptation_error)
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/site-packages/learn2learn/algorithms/maml.py", line 169, in adapt
    self.module = maml_update(self.module, self.lr, gradients)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'gradients' referenced before assignment
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'c10::CUDAError'
  what():  CUDA error: unspecified launch failure
CUDA kernel errors might be asynchronously reported at some other API call,so the stacktrace below might be incorrect.
For debugging consider passing CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1.
Exception raised from query at ../aten/src/ATen/cuda/CUDAEvent.h:95 (most recent call first):
frame #0: c10::Error::Error(c10::SourceLocation, std::string) + 0x42 (0x7f5036ae4a22 in /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libc10.so)
frame #1: c10d::ProcessGroupNCCL::WorkNCCL::finishedGPUExecutionInternal() const + 0x132 (0x7f50dbec70e2 in /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #2: c10d::ProcessGroupNCCL::WorkNCCL::isCompleted() + 0x50 (0x7f50dbec8d40 in /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #3: c10d::ProcessGroupNCCL::workCleanupLoop() + 0x11c (0x7f50dbec975c in /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_python.so)
frame #4: <unknown function> + 0xc71f (0x7f50da8aa71f in /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/lib/libtorch_cuda.so)
frame #5: <unknown function> + 0x7ea5 (0x7f50e43e6ea5 in /lib64/libpthread.so.0)
frame #6: clone + 0x6d (0x7f50e410fb0d in /lib64/libc.so.6)

/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:216: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 6 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
ERROR:torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.api:failed (exitcode: -6) local_rank: 5 (pid: 158275) of binary: /home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/bin/python
/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/multiprocessing/errors/__init__.py:367: UserWarning: 

**********************************************************************
               CHILD PROCESS FAILED WITH NO ERROR_FILE                
**********************************************************************
CHILD PROCESS FAILED WITH NO ERROR_FILE
Child process 158275 (local_rank 5) FAILED (exitcode -6)
Error msg: Signal 6 (SIGABRT) received by PID 158275
Without writing an error file to <N/A>.
While this DOES NOT affect the correctness of your application,
no trace information about the error will be available for inspection.
Consider decorating your top level entrypoint function with
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors.record. Example:

  from torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors import record

  @record
  def trainer_main(args):
     # do train
**********************************************************************
  warnings.warn(_no_error_file_warning_msg(rank, failure))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 702, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/elastic/multiprocessing/errors/__init__.py", line 361, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 698, in main
    run(args)
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/run.py", line 689, in run
    elastic_launch(
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 116, in __call__
    return launch_agent(self._config, self._entrypoint, list(args))
  File "/home/miranda9/miniconda3/envs/meta_learning_a100/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/distributed/launcher/api.py", line 244, in launch_agent
    raise ChildFailedError(
torch.distributed.elastic.multiprocessing.errors.ChildFailedError: 
****************************************************************************************************************************************
  /home/miranda9/diversity-for-predictive-success-of-meta-learning/div_src/diversity_src/experiment_mains/main_dist_maml_l2l.py FAILED  
========================================================================================================================================
Root Cause:
[0]:
  time: 2022-02-04_20:26:43
  rank: 5 (local_rank: 5)
  exitcode: -6 (pid: 158275)
  error_file: <N/A>
  msg: "Signal 6 (SIGABRT) received by PID 158275"
========================================================================================================================================
Other Failures:
[1]:
  time: 2022-02-04_20:26:43
  rank: 6 (local_rank: 6)
  exitcode: 1 (pid: 158280)
  error_file: <N/A>
  msg: "Process failed with exitcode 1"
****************************************************************************************************************************************
```

but different variations of the way to set up the script doesn't work.

In summary, how is one suppose to use `torch.distributed.run` such that TWO or MORE scripts can run at once and they are all distributed?

---

Related:

- main discussion for a solution here: https://github.com/learnables/learn2learn/issues/263
- https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/multiprocessing-failed-with-torch-distributed-launch-module/33056
- base code: https://github.com/learnables/learn2learn/blob/master/examples/vision/distributed_maml.py